# ZF2 form file upload. best practice: don't reupload file on item edition

Tags: file, upload, zend-framework2

I had this problem many times before and I want like to have advices about what will be the best to deal with that:
I have a form to create a new item with label, description, etc ... and with an input file in order to upload a document; this last field is mandatory.

When I want to edit this item (so after saving it first into a db or whatever) I want the file field to not be mandatory anymore and if the user doesn't select a new file, I will keep the previous filename here.

So what's the best way to do that with Zend Framework 2 ? I already have my model, form and input filters set and everything is working well.

I was thinking about:
- having a different inputFilter configuration in edition mode,
- or having a validator for the input field checking that a filename was not already set for the entity attached to the form, 
- or storing the current filename in a input hidden field (not really secure like that)
- or ???

Thank you in advance and have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change input filter in controller

```
$form = new \Zend\Form\Form();
$filters = $form->getInputFilter();
$filters->remove('file');
$filters->add(array(
    'name' => 'file',
    'required' => true,
    //...
));
```

or you can make function with this logic in input filter class